# weblate: new keys from json file aren't appearing

Tags: json, weblate

There is a problem in weblate that I can't solve so I need the help.
My case is:

1. New component was created  for web app and it has new keys for translation. I created the new component in the weblate for these new keys and added path of JSON files to translate.
   Everything was good and component with new keys was shown in the weblate.
2. Next day new keys were added to the same JSON file, but I don't see these new keys in the weblate in source language.
   I verified in the weblate that JSON file is up to date and has new keys.
   I downloaded this file from weblate - new key are there.
   I uploaded this JSON file to weblate manually - the message 'Processed 19 strings from the uploaded files.' but I still see only 17 keys in the weblate.

What is wrong there? Please help.

[Update] if start translation to new language all keys are present.
So it's a problem with updating for already used source files.

Comment: New strings should be added in the VCS repository, you seem to be uploading new translation in the web interface, what will never add new strings, just update existing ones. See https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/continuous.html

Comment: Sure new JSON file was updated by developer and changes were uploaded in the repository. I mentioned that I verified the file that is used by weblate now - it's new and has all changes. But new keys from this file were not added into weblate component automatically. If I create new translation (new language) the weblate uses the same file from the repository and there are all keys.

Comment: The problem was resolved. Looks like the weblate was locked by some reason and new commits for several components couldn't be pulled or pushed. I have had to reset all changes for these components in the local (weblate) repository and now it works fine. New changes in JSON files is up to date. Hope it'll help for somebody in future)